# Why do adjacent buttons have double border except when floated right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an `<a>` and a `<button>` in a bootstrap btn-group. All else being equal, making the parent btn-group div `class="float-right"`(bootstrap class) causes the borders of the two buttons to merge into a single line which I find desirable. `float-left` as well as not using any float option both leave a thicker double border between the two which I don't like.

[image: float-left]`float-left / no float`

[image: float-right]`float-right`

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified [[float-right or float-left here]]">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info text-nowrap" href="...">
            Login
        </a>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button">Help</button>
    </div>
```

Why is this behavior inconsistent or what can I do to get that single line without floating right?

Comment: I just checked the shared html with bootstrap 4.5 and it worked same with float-right/float-left/no float. I think one your custom classes might be overriding the default behaviour. To confirm this try running shared html in a dedicated html file having linked bootstrap resources.

Comment: Yeah, [not seeing it](https://jsfiddle.net/q0p4jhs6/).